# Struts logic tag to iterate over a list

Tags: struts-1

At this link:
http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-logic-iterate-example/
example #2:
they show usage of struts  tag to iterate over a `List` `listUsers` . But the example shows the `List` set as an attribute in the request directly. Is it possible to use this tag if the `List` is an attribute in the corresponding form bean? using the syntax at the link, I get (expectedly):

Cannot find bean: "`listUsers`" in any scope

Answer (score 2):

If the list is set to the form you need to have following syntax in the iterate tag

```
    <logic:iterate id="myid" name="<nameofform>" property="<listname>">
        <bean:write name="myid" />
    </logic:iterate>
```

Form name is the name defines in struts-config.xml.